# How to set workspaces with different resolution

Tags: linux, resolution, xorg, workspace

I have only one monitor, but I want to set two workspace with different resolutions. Because some window is too large for the native resolution of my monitor. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

The method differs depending on your PC and graphics card settings. For AMD for example, you can adjust different resolutions from the Catalyst Center. For Ubuntu, you can use console commands to access nVidia settings. Check out a forum thread for this question here:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=772883

For Windows legacy versions, there's a thread which deals with that same question worth checking out here:

http://www.cnet.com/forums/discussions/1-monitor-2-desktops-with-different-resolutions-297146/

You can also use 3rd party software to configure resolution like:

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/finally-get-two-functional-desktops-with-actual-multiple-monitors/

And here's a good list of programs that allow you to customize virtual desktops:

http://www.howtogeek.com/130650/the-best-free-programs-for-using-virtual-desktops-in-windows/

Comment: But I only has one actual monitor, I want two resolution for different virtual desktop.

Comment: @godblessfq some of those tools allow you to do that. You'll have to check their documentation and see which works best for you.

Comment: Probably this is not a issue of the graphic card. Thank you anyway.